# Why is my Kendo ListBox TransferAll not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using the two listbox control for kendo and the transferAll command does not work if nothing is selected.  Once any item is selected the transferAll will work as expected.  I would expect that transferAll would work regardless if something is selected or not.

Kendo Control I am Talking about:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/listbox/overview

Control in action on telerik examples:
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listbox/index

The data for the list box is not present on render and an async call is made to get the data after rendering.  Could the missing link happen at that point?

Comment: it would be great if you share your code.

Comment: Can you create a Dojo showing the lack of transfer ?  Did you try disabling the buttons on configuration and enabling them in the dataBound event handler ?